# Drawing of Euro Symbol Using PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

I have drawn the following figure, showing a Euro symbol:

```
% http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Euro_Construction.svg

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\psset{
  unit = 0.8,
  linejoin = 1
}

\begin{pspicture}(-7.5,-6)(4.26,6)
 \pscustom[
   fillstyle = solid,
   fillcolor = yellow!70
 ]{
  \psline(\calc{6*sin(2*acot(6/5*sec(2/9*pi)+tan(2/9*pi)))},
          \calc{6*cos(2*acot(6/5*sec(2/9*pi)+tan(2/9*pi)))})%
         (\calc{5*cos(2/9*pi)},\calc{5*sin(2/9*pi)})
  \psarc(0,0){5}{40}{\calc{90+round(acosd(3/10),9)}}
  \psline(\calc{-sqrt(91)/2},1.5)%
         (\calc{75/2*cos(2/9*pi)/(6+5*sin(2/9*pi))},1.5)%
         (\calc{65/2*cos(2/9*pi)/(6+5*sin(2/9*pi))},0.5)%
         (\calc{-3/2*sqrt(11)},0.5)
  \psarc(0,0){5}%
         {\calc{ 90+round(acosd(1/10),9)}}%
         {\calc{270-round(acosd(1/10),9)}}
  \psline(\calc{-3/2*sqrt(11)},-0.5)%
         (\calc{55/2*cos(2/9*pi)/(6+5*sin(2/9*pi))},-0.5)%
         (\calc{45/2*cos(2/9*pi)/(6+5*sin(2/9*pi))},-1.5)%
         (\calc{-sqrt(91)/2},-1.5)
  \psarc(0,0){5}{\calc{270-round(acosd(3/10),9)}}{320}
  \psline(\calc{ 5*cos(2/9*pi)},\calc{-5*sin(2/9*pi)})%
         (\calc{ 5*cos(2/9*pi)},\calc{-sqrt(36-25*cos(2/9*pi)^2)})
  \psarcn(0,0){6}%
         {\calc{270+round(atand(5*cos(2/9*pi)/sqrt(36-25*cos(2/9*pi)^2)),9)}}%
         {\calc{270-round(acosd(1/4),9)}}
  \psline(\calc{-6*cos(1/4)},-1.5)%
         (-7.5,-1.5)%
         (\calc{5*cos(2/9*pi)/(6+5*sin(2/9*pi))-15/2},-0.5)%
         (\calc{-6*cos(1/12)},-0.5)
  \psarcn(0,0){6}%
         {\calc{270-round(acosd(1/12),9)}}%
         {\calc{ 90+round(acosd(1/12),9)}}
  \psline(\calc{-6*cos(1/12)},0.5)%
         (-7.5,0.5)%
         (\calc{5*cos(2/9*pi)/(6+5*sin(2/9*pi))-15/2},1.5)%
         (\calc{-6*cos(1/4)},1.5)
  \psarcn(0,0){6}%
         {\calc{90+round(acosd(1/4),9)}}%
         {\calc{round(atand(sec(2/9*pi)/10*(36-25*sin(1/18*pi)+60*sin(2/9*pi))%
                            /(6+5*sin(2/9*pi))),9)}}%
 }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Is there a way of drawing the same figure using PSTricks without all the hard-coded values?

(See the link for how to make a geometrical construction of the symbol.)

Comment: Which hard-coded values are you referring to? The angles would be the same regardless of the size. The lengths are relative to `xunit`/`yunit`/`unit`, so that doesn't really leave much else other than including an existing symbol (from a font, say, [`eurosym`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eurosym)) or including the image after converting it.

Comment: @Werner I'm thinking of using something like, say, [`pst-eucl`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-eucl) to 'construct' the symbol.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "without hard-coded values", please. Are you interested in scaling the image and the hard-coded values make this difficult? Or you just want something that is *cleaner*? Even with [`pst-eucl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-eucl) I don't think you'll get much cleaner. I still think [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192573/5764) is the easiest *and* uses PSTricks.

Comment: By 'hard-coded' I'm thinking of all the values inside the `\calc`s. If I can construct the symbol and only use the values on the image in the link, I would like that.

Comment: @Werner: Your last link titled `my answer` points to a wrong target, I think.

Comment: @Pleasedon'ttouch: It's for 10K-users only, as [I deleted that answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/unmKb.png).

Comment: @Werner: I see. Directing deleted links to the question for lower-rep users seems to be a bad feature implemented in SX because it is confusing/misleading. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Euro symbol *is* hard coded (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:EuroConstLarge.png). However, you can simplify it. Straight connections between two points can be omitted `\pscustom` does it by default when building the path:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\pstVerb{ 
  /c40 {40 cos }bind def
  /s40 {40 sin }bind def
  /s65 {6 5 s40 mul add }bind def
}
\begin{pspicture}(-7.5,-7.5)(7.5,7.5)
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black!20]{%
  \psarc(0,0){5}{40}{! 180 0.3 ATAN1 sub }
  \psline(! 37.5 c40 mul s65 div 1.5)(! 32.5 c40 mul s65 div 0.5)
  \psarc(0,0){5}{!180 0.1 ATAN1 sub}{!180 0.1 ATAN1 add}
  \psline(! 27.5 c40 mul s65 div -0.5)(! 22.5 c40 mul s65 div -1.5)
  \psarc(0,0){5}{!180 0.3 ATAN1 add}{320}  
  \psarcn(0,0){6}{! 270 5 c40 mul 36 25 c40 dup mul mul sub sqrt div ATAN1 add } 
                 {! 270 0.25 Acos sub }
  \psline(-7.5,-1.5)(!5 c40 mul s65 div 7.5 sub -0.5)
  \psarcn(0,0){6}{!180 1 12 atan add}{!180 1 12 atan sub} 
  \psline(-7.5,0.5)(! 5 c40 mul s65 div 7.5 sub 1.5)
  \psarcn(0,0){6}{!180 1.5 6 atan sub}
          {! 1 c40 div 10 div 36 25 10 sin mul sub 60 s40 mul add mul s65 div ATAN1}
 \closepath
}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Just to be clear: What do you mean by "streight lines"? (All lines are streight.)

Comment: Compare my `\psline` sequences and yours. You have four coordinates and I used only two

Answer (score 1):

A solution with MetaPost which needs only the radius. Run it with `context <file>`:

```
\starttext
\setupcolors[state=start]

\startuseMPgraphic{dummy}
boolean trace_euro ; trace_euro := false ;
vardef euro_symbol = image ( % begin_of_euro
 if unknown euro_radius   : euro_radius := 2cm; fi;
 if unknown euro_width    : euro_width := 3euro_radius/16; fi;
 if unknown euro_r_offset : euro_r_offset:= euro_width; fi;
 if unknown euro_l_offset : euro_l_offset := euro_radius/32 ; fi ;
 if unknown euro_l_shift  : euro_l_shift := euro_r_offset ; fi ;
 if unknown euro_v_delta  : euro_v_delta := euro_width/4 ; fi ;
save
  outer_circle, inner_circle, hor_bar,
  right_line, right_slant, top_slant, bot_slant,
  euro_circle, euro_topbar, euro_botbar ;
path
  outer_circle, inner_circle, hor_bar,
  right_line, right_slant, top_slant, bot_slant,
  euro_circle, euro_topbar, euro_botbar ;
outer_circle := fullcircle scaled euro_radius ;
inner_circle := fullcircle scaled (euro_radius-euro_width) ;
if trace_euro : 
  for i = outer_circle, inner_circle :
    draw i withpen pencircle scaled 1pt withcolor .5white ;
  endfor ; 
fi ;
right_line := (lrcorner outer_circle -- urcorner outer_circle) shifted (-euro_r_offset,0) ;
outer_circle := outer_circle cutbefore right_line ;
right_slant := point 0 of outer_circle -- origin shifted (0,ypart lrcorner outer_circle) ;
euro_circle := buildcycle(outer_circle, right_line, reverse inner_circle, reverse right_slant) ;
hor_bar := (-euro_radius,0) -- (euro_radius,0) ;
top_slant := right_slant shifted (-euro_radius+euro_r_offset-euro_l_offset,0) ;
bot_slant := top_slant shifted (0,-euro_l_shift) ;
if trace_euro : 
  for i = right_line, right_slant, top_slant, bot_slant :
    draw i withpen pencircle scaled 1pt withcolor .5white ;
  endfor ; 
fi ;
euro_topbar := buildcycle (top_slant, hor_bar shifted (0, euro_v_delta),
                right_slant, hor_bar shifted (0, euro_v_delta+euro_width/2)) ;
euro_botbar := buildcycle (bot_slant, hor_bar shifted (0,-euro_v_delta),
                right_slant, hor_bar shifted (0,-euro_v_delta-euro_width/2)) ;
for i = euro_circle, euro_topbar, euro_botbar :
  draw i withpen pencircle scaled 0 ;
endfor ;
for i = euro_circle, euro_topbar, euro_botbar :
  fill i withpen pencircle scaled 0 ;
endfor ;
if trace_euro : 
  drawpoints euro_circle withcolor red;
  drawpoints euro_topbar withcolor green ;
  drawpoints euro_botbar withcolor blue ;
fi ;
) enddef ; % end_of_euro
euro_radius := 4cm ; draw euro_symbol withcolor 0.8yellow ;
trace_euro := true ; draw euro_symbol shifted (5cm,0) ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\useMPgraphic{dummy}
\stoptext
```

[image]