# Euro symbol for math mode

Tags: symbols

The code \euro gives the symbol for the Euro-currency, it does not function in math mode. How can I get the Euro symbol in math mode?

Comment: Have you tried the currency package?

Comment: @Jet I never tried the currency package

Comment: [On ctan](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/currency/currency_doc.pdf) it handles many configurations, including mathmode

Comment: \euro is not defined in standard latex, so you should show a complete example so that we don't have to guess what you are actually doing.

Comment: Can't you simply use U+20AC EURO SIGN ?

Comment: `marvosym.sty` is a better option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution is from [link 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110990/140814).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\euro{} in text mode

$\text{\euro}$ in math mode

\itshape $\text{\euro}$ in math mode
\end{document}
```

The second solution is from [link 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110979/140814).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amstext} % for \text
\DeclareRobustCommand{\officialeuro}{%
  \ifmmode\expandafter\text\fi
  {\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eurosym}\selectfont e}}

\begin{document}
\euro{} in text mode

$\euro$ in math mode

\itshape $\euro$ in math mode
\end{document}
```

By the way, `\euro` could be replaced by `\EUR` in the `marvosym` package, and `\wasyeuro` in the `wasysym` package.

While both the first and second solutions have a disadvantage: the produced symbol could be effected by `\itshape`, `\bfseries` and so on. And I don't know how to improve them.

The third solution improved from [link 3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192592/140814) is recommended that the produced symbol couldn't be effected by `\itshape`, `\bfseries` and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\euro}{%
\scalerel*{%
\pstVerb{ 
/c40 {40 cos }bind def
/s40 {40 sin }bind def
/s65 {6 5 s40 mul add }bind def
}
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-6)(6,6)
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black]{%
\psarc(0,0){5}{40}{! 180 0.3 ATAN1 sub }
\psline(! 37.5 c40 mul s65 div 1.5)(! 32.5 c40 mul s65 div 0.5)
\psarc(0,0){5}{!180 0.1 ATAN1 sub}{!180 0.1 ATAN1 add}
\psline(! 27.5 c40 mul s65 div -0.5)(! 22.5 c40 mul s65 div -1.5)
\psarc(0,0){5}{!180 0.3 ATAN1 add}{320}  
\psarcn(0,0){6}{! 270 5 c40 mul 36 25 c40 dup mul mul sub sqrt div ATAN1 add } 
{! 270 0.25 Acos sub }
\psline(-7.5,-1.5)(!5 c40 mul s65 div 7.5 sub -0.5)
\psarcn(0,0){6}{!180 1 12 atan add}{!180 1 12 atan sub} 
\psline(-7.5,0.5)(! 5 c40 mul s65 div 7.5 sub 1.5)
\psarcn(0,0){6}{!180 1.5 6 atan sub}
{! 1 c40 div 10 div 36 25 10 sin mul sub 60 s40 mul add mul s65 div ATAN1}
\closepath
}
\end{pspicture}
}{X}%
}

\begin{document}
\euro{} in text mode

$\euro$ in math mode

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a hammer vs [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125063/searching-for-euro-symbol?rq=1) but `currency` is a cool package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{currency}

%Easy to define your set up with keys
\DefineCurrency{EUR}{
    name={euro},
    plural={euros},
    symbol={\euro},
    iso={EUR},
%   kind=iso, %
    kind=symbol,
%   base=2,
}

\begin{document}

If I get $\dEUR{10}$ per hour I would get \dEUR[prefix=k]{10} in 1000 hours. 

\end{document}
```

[image]