# LaTex (Overleaf) - \euro not working inside equations

Tags: symbols, eurosym

I'm a newcomer to this community. I've relied on your explanations to solve various LaTeX-related issues as part of my learning journey. Currently, I'm in the process of writing my thesis and have run into a huge problem.

These are the lines I'll refer to.

```
\begin{equation}
K_{\$,\max} \cdot E_c - c_0 = 15.88 \frac{\euro}{GJ} 
\cdot 3500\frac{kWh}{anno} - 872 \frac{\euro}{anno} 
= 54780 \frac{\euro}{anno}
\end{equation}
```

When I employ the `\euro` command in LaTeX, it outputs either 'e' or '£' instead of '€'. I have already included the `eurosym` package, and the `\euro` command functions correctly outside of the `\frac` command. However, when used within `\frac`, it does not produce the desired output. I've attempted various solutions, including declaring the `\euro` command as a math variable, but the issue persists.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: As you've discovered, `\euro` is a text-mode macro. Have you tried replacing instances of `\euro` that occur in math mode with `\textup{\euro}`?

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: What does "anno" mean? Maybe "per annum"?

Comment: Possible `\texteuro will work there.

Comment: Seems to be duplicate to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648170/euro-symbol-for-math-mode

Comment: Please note that you're output will not be typographically correct to represent any of your units. Take a look at the `siunitx` package to get typographically sound output of SI units. In particular, your output of for instance `kWh` will not mean kilo Watt hours, but will mean "*k* times *W* times *h*".